# Matrix differential equation with DSolve doesn't work

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I'm trying to solve matrix differential equation with DSolve, but I got an error.

```
L = 1 - t;
f1 = Integrate[1/(1 - u)^2, {u, 0, t}]; 
d = Table[If[k == n, 0, ((k*n)/(k^2 - n^2))*
           Exp[I*Pi^2*(k^2 - n^2)*f1]], {k, 4}, {n, 4}]; 
g = D[L, t]/L; 
B[t_] = {b1[t], b2[t], b3[t], b4[t]}; 


sol = DSolve[B'[t] ==- 2 g d.B[t], B[t], t]
```

The error :

```
DSolve::nolist: List encountered within {ConditionalExpression[(b1^\[Prime])[t]==(2 (-(2/3) E^(3 I Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>] t) b2[t]-3/8 E^(8 <<3>> t) b3[t]-4/15 E^(15 I <<1>> Power[<<2>>] t) b4[t]))/(1-t),Re[t]<=1||t\[NotElement]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]],ConditionalExpression[(b2^\[Prime])[t]==(2 (<<1>>))/(1-t),Re[t]<=1||t\[NotElement]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]],<<21>>[<<1>>==<<1>>,<<1>>],ConditionalExpression[(b4^\[Prime])[t]==(2 (<<1>>))/(1-t),Re[t]<=1||t\[NotElement]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]]}. There should be no lists on either side of the equations.
```

I have tried this procedure on solving simpler matrix differential equation of the same format and it worked :

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
X[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]};
sol = DSolve[X'[t] == a.X[t], X[t], t]
```

Output :

```
{{x1[t] -> -(1/22) E^((5 t)/2 - (Sqrt[33] t)/
      2) (-11 - Sqrt[33] - 11 E^(Sqrt[33] t) + 
       Sqrt[33] E^(Sqrt[33] t)) C[1] + (
    2 E^((5 t)/2 - (Sqrt[33] t)/2) (-1 + E^(Sqrt[33] t)) C[2])/Sqrt[
    33], 
x2[t] -> Sqrt[3/11] E^((5 t)/2 - (Sqrt[33] t)/2) (-1 + E^(Sqrt[33] t)) C[
         1] + 1/22 E^((5 t)/2 - (Sqrt[33] t)/
          2) (11 - Sqrt[33] + 11 E^(Sqrt[33] t) + 
           Sqrt[33] E^(Sqrt[33] t)) C[2]}}
```

Comment: Consider switching away from `If` (which is really more appropriate for program flow control) to `Piecewise` or `Boole` in your conditional definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DSolve` can't solve the system. It has complex numbers. You  can try `NDSolve`

First we try `DSolve`

```
ClearAll[u, t, B, b, k, n];
L = 1 - t;
f1 = Integrate[1/(1 - u)^2, {u, 0, t}, GenerateConditions -> False];
d = Table[
   If[k == n, 0, ((k*n)/(k^2 - n^2))*Exp[I*Pi^2*(k^2 - n^2)*f1]], {k, 
    4}, {n, 4}];
g = D[L, t]/L;
B[t_] := {b1[t], b2[t], b3[t], b4[t]};
odeSys = MapThread[Equal, {B'[t], -2 g d . B[t]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
sol = DSolve[odeSys, B[t], t]
```

Returns after few second unevaluated. No errors or warnings generated. It just can't be solved analytically.

Try numerically. But need some IC. So made up some random ones

```
deps = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
ic = MapThread[Equal, {B[t] /. t -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
sol = NDSolve[{odeSys, ic}, deps, {t, 0, .9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But solution is complex

```
 Evaluate[b1[t] /. sol] /. t -> .5
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can plot the real part and the imaginary part separately

```
Plot[Evaluate[Im@Evaluate[B[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, .9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re@Evaluate[B[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, .9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
 Plot[Evaluate[Abs@Evaluate[B[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, .9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or can use `ReImPlot`

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate[Evaluate[B[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, .9}, 
 PlotLegends -> deps]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot man! 1 question, what is the significance of `deps`? I tried replacing all the `deps` with `B[t]` as saw no difference.

Comment: Oh and 1 more thing. If `B[t]` contains a lot of elements (e.g. 100), is there a quick way to write its elements instead of writing `B[t_]={b1[t],b2[t],b3[t],....}`?

Comment: @ForacleFunacle ` what is the significance of deps`  normally for `NDSolve` it is better to use  just `b` instead of `b[t]` for the dependent variable. It makes things little easier to post process. But both will work. For `DSolve` I use `b[t]` and not `b`.   See help on `NDSolve`. This is how they do the examples. So `deps` was just a lazy way remove the `t`, that is all.

Comment: @ForacleFunacle `If B[t] contains a lot of elements (e.g. 100), is there a quick way to write its elements `  you can try `B[t_] = Table[ToExpression["b" <> ToString[n] <> "[t]"], {n, 100}]`